# Program keep executing even though all latch.countdown() are called

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this simple schema:

```
int parallelism = 4; //4 tasks
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(parallelism);

for(int i=0;i<parallelism;i++){
   executor.execute(new MyTask());
}

latch.await();
System.out.println("done");
```

Where Task just calls

```
public void run(){
      System.out.println("working");
      latch.countDown();
}
```

Even though execution gives me:

```
working
working
working
working
done
```

the overall program keep executing! How come?

Comment: It is working as expected.. The main thread is waiting until all other threads have called `countDown()`. What did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shut down your `Executor`.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    // ...
    executor.shutdown();
    while ( executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        System.out.println("This is taking too long.");
    }
```

Even though all of your runnables have completed the `Executor` keeps the threads in a pool. These are what is holding up your exit. The `main` thread will not exit until all non-daemon threads have completed.

Also see [Turning an ExecutorService to daemon in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13883293/823393) for another alternative - making the `Executor` use daemon threads.