# Why does the ExecutorService interface not implement AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, try-with-resources

Failing to call `shutdown()` on a thread executor will result in a never terminating application.

Best practice to shut down the ExecutorService is this:

```
ExecutorService service = null;
try {
  service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  // add tasks to thread executor
  …
} finally {
  if (service != null) service.shutdown();
}
```

Since Java knows the try-with-resources concept, wouldn't it be nice if we could do this?

```
try (service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
{
  // add tasks to thread executor
  …
}
```

Comment: Nice question though ... that thought never occurred to me ;-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883293/turning-an-executorservice-to-daemon-in-java

Comment: There are tons of "resourceful" non-`Closeable` APIs in the JDK

Comment: See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72267126/642706) with an important update for Java 19+.

Comment: I had this question just now & searched in SO & got this!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) has actually **two** shutdown-related methods; based on the simple fact that **both** ways of shutting down a service make sense.

Thus: how would you auto-close a service then? In a consistent manner that works for everybody?!

So, the reasonable explanation in my eyes: you can't make an ExecutorService a AutoClosable because that service does not have a single "close" like operation; but two!

And if you think you could make good use of such an auto-closing service, writing up your own implementation using "delegation" would be a 5 minute thing! Or probably 10 minutes, because you would create one version calling `shutdown()` as close operation; and one that does `shutdownNow()` instead.

Comment: You're probably right ;) What i really wanted to say is, that it is completely possible to wrap the functionality of `ExecutorService` into a class that supports `AutoCloseable`

Comment: Additional reasoning to not make ExecutorService AutoClosable in JDK - this is a service, not an a resourse... Exactly same reason for ExceturService to not extend Closeable interface.

Comment: Thread pool is a valid resource. And choice between cleanup methods is hardly an excuse for not having a default cleanup method

Comment: I don't think having 2 methods justifies not ensuring the resource as auto-cleanable. Its important when designing to do as much as we can to help the client code do the right thing.

Answer (score 29):

This is a mediocre workaround

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try (Closeable close = service::shutdown) {

}
```

Or, if the checked exception bothers you, you could write:

```
interface MyCloseable extends AutoCloseable {
    void close();
}
```

And then

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try (MyCloseable close = service::shutdown) {

}
```

Of course, you must never ever put anything between the assignment and the `try` statement, nor use the `service` local variable after the `try` statement.

Given the caveats, just use `finally` instead.

Comment: Hi, this force me to declare also a `} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }` - how could I avoid that?

Comment: @adrhc: Updated my answer with a possible workaround

Answer (score 20):

## `ExecutorService` is `AutoCloseable` in Java 19+

Starting from [Java 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_19), [`ExecutorService` implements `AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close()).

The default implementation invokes `shutdown()` and waits for tasks to complete with `awaitTermination` in a loop. It calls `shutdownNow()` if interrupted.

## Google Guava

For earlier Java, you can use [Guava's `ForwardingExecutorService`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingExecutorService.html) to decorate `ExeuctorService` as `AutoCloseable` yourself:

```java
class CloseableExecutorService extends ForwardingExecutorService implements AutoCloseable {

  private final ExecutorService delegate;

  CloseableExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate) {
    this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  protected ExecutorService delegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    // copy paste from JDK 19 EA
    boolean terminated = isTerminated();
    if (!terminated) {
      shutdown();
      boolean interrupted = false;
      while (!terminated) {
        try {
          terminated = awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          if (!interrupted) {
            shutdownNow();
            interrupted = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (interrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed this one! I am gad they did it! Should have been done much sooner!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where AutoCloseable is that useful for an Executor.  try-with-resources is for things that can be initialized, used, and released within the scope of a method. This works great for things like files, network connections, jdbc resources, etc., where they get opened, used, and cleaned up quickly. But an executor, especially a threadpool, is something you want available for a long time period, probably over the lifetime of the application, and will tend to get injected into things like singleton services, which can have a method that the DI framework knows to call on application shutdown to clean up the executor. This usage pattern works fine without try-with-resources.

Also, a big motivator behind try-with-resources is making sure exceptions don't get masked. That's not a consideration so much with executors, all the exception-throwing will be happening in the tasks submitted to the executor, 
exception-masking is not an issue.

Comment: Everything is in the context of a single method: the `main` method of the program.