# Is using a lambda a safe, correct, and equivalent workaround for classes that do not implement AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources, autocloseable

Background: I use the Java class `InitialDirContext` to access LDAP directories.  [Unfortunately](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7057061), it does not implement interface `AutoCloseable`, so it cannot be used in [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks.

Here is the original code I wrote: ([inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612120/257299))

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
// Populate 'props' here.
final InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);
Exception e0 = null;
try {
    // use 'context' here
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Only save a reference to the exception.
    e0 = e;
    // Why re-throw?
    // If finally block does not throw, this exception must be thrown.
    throw e;
}
finally {
    try {
        context.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e2) {
        if (null != e0) {
            e0.addSuppressed(e2);
            // No need to re-throw 'e0' here.  It was (re-)thrown above.
        }
        else {
            throw e2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Is this a safe, correct, and equivalent replacement?**

```
try (final AutoCloseable dummy = () -> context.close()) {
    // use 'context' here
}
```

I *think* the answer is yes, but I want to confirm.  I tried Googling for this pattern, but I found nothing.  It is so simple!  Thus, I am suspicious it may not be correct.

**Edit:** I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395429/257299) with a similar pattern.

Comment: This seems quite clever. Great question.

Comment: The Java Language Specification has a *translation* (equivalent code) for it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1-140

Comment: Could be written as `final AutoCloseable dummy = context::close`

Comment: "Thus, I am suspicious it may not be correct." I would honestly be more suspicious about the correctness of the first code. I think the second is more self-evidently correct, because it's just simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395429/257299) you linked to, it is not strictly equivalent because you have to either catch or throw `Exception` from `AutoCloseable.close()` and you must be sure not to do anything with `context` after the `try` block because it is not out of scope as if `InitialDirContext` directly implemented `AutoCloseable`. Still I agree with others that this workaround is quite nice.

Of course, you could also extend `InitialDirContext` and make it implement `AutoCloseable` directly or (for final classes) use a delegator pattern and wrap the target object.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TryWithResourcesAutoCloseableWrapper {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
    variant1(props);
    variant2(props);
    variant3(props);
  }

  public static void variant1(Properties props) throws NamingException {
    final InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);
    try (final AutoCloseable dummy = context::close) {
      lookupMX(context);
    }
    catch (NamingException ne) {
      throw ne;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void variant2(Properties props) throws NamingException {
    final InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);
    try (final MyCloseable dummy = context::close) {
      lookupMX(context);
    }
  }

  public static void variant3(Properties props) throws NamingException {
    try (final MyInitialDirContext context = new MyInitialDirContext(props)) {
      lookupMX(context);
    }
  }

  private static void lookupMX(InitialDirContext context) throws NamingException {
    System.out.println(context.getAttributes("scrum-master.de", new String[] { "MX" }));
  }

  public interface MyCloseable extends AutoCloseable {
    void close() throws NamingException;
  }

  public static class MyInitialDirContext extends InitialDirContext implements AutoCloseable {
    public MyInitialDirContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws NamingException {
      super(environment);
    }
  }

}
```

A few more thoughts about how to use these workarounds:

- Both `variant1` and `variant2` come at the cost of `dummy` objects which inside the `try` block you will never use, unless you cast them to `InitialDirContext` first. Instead, you could directly use the outer `context` objects, of course, which is also what you suggested.
- In `variant3` the auto-closable `context` object directly has the correct (sub-)type, so you can actually work with it seamlessly without casting or dummy object. This comes at the cost of a special subclass.

Comment: **Update:** I made my sample code do something meaningful (an actual DNS lookup).

Comment: Sorry, I took so long to accept this answer.  It is very detailed!  The best answers on SO will give a variety of possibilities and help the reader the narrow down the best.  Cheers.