# Why does my custom ExecutorService bean not call the shutdown method in Java 19 with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-19

An `ExecutorService` bean does not call the shutdown method on Java 19 with SpringBoot (2.7.12 or 3.1.0). This results in `@SpringBootTest` tests never completing.

This only happens when you have a custom `ExecutorService` bean, implements the `SchedulingConfigurer` and includes the `@Scheduled` annotation.

The `@Bean` JavaDoc states that the `destroyMethod` is inferred, and `shutdown` is one of the options.

The following code breaks

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduleConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    }

    /**
     * Works if @Scheduled is not included.
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
    protected void schedule() {

    }
}
```

Test never completes.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(
        classes =
                {ScheduleConfig.class})
class TestIT {

    @Test
    void test() {
        //NOOP
    }
}
```

A workaround is to explicitly set the `destroyMethod` like

```
 @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because [jdk 19 start implementing `AutoClosable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close())

[DisposableBeanAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DisposableBeanAdapter.html) will invoke `close` by default for bean implementing `AutoClosable`

Referring to the method close, it will block until terminated, and as your cron expression is set to invoke at 1 o'clock, it will terminate when the scheduled job finished at 1 o'clock, that's why it seems never completed. You may try `* * * * * *` and it will finish immediately.

```java
    @Override
    default void close() {
        boolean terminated = isTerminated();
        if (!terminated) {
            shutdown();
            boolean interrupted = false;
            while (!terminated) {
                try {
                    terminated = awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    if (!interrupted) {
                        shutdownNow();
                        interrupted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (interrupted) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

Related: [Why does the ExecutorService interface not implement AutoCloseable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41393417/7928721)