# Stop infinite loop in threadpool Java

Tags: java, while-loop, threadpool, infinite-loop, threadpoolexecutor

I have this code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Boolean> f = executor.submit(() -> {
    if (true) {
        while (true);
    }
    return false;
});
try {
    System.out.println(f.get(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

While I'm running the program, I get the Exception like I should, but the while loop continues to run and the program does not stop.
I tried `executor.shutdown()`, `executor.shutdownNow()`, `f.cancel(true)` and more.
Does anyone have any idea? I'm trying to solve this for three days.

Comment: Make it a daemon thread and it'll die with the program.

Comment: Change your loop to `while (!Thread.interrupted());`

Comment: How I enter a daemon thread to the threadpool? @shmosel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13883412/1553851

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using a busy loop, but the way you'd do that is to stop if the thread has been interrupted:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    // do something
}
```

Rather than use a busy loop, your thread should be waiting on a signal or an event. Or even polling at a set interval. A busy loop like the one you describe will simply use up the CPU.

For instance, you can simply call [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) on any object, and your thread will be woken up upon being interrupted.

```
try {
    (new Object()).wait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Interrupted
}
```

See here for a discussion of thread signalling: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html